# Exception while installing Sitecore Commerce 9 Update 2 - No registration found for extension > 'ExpandArchive' of type 'Task'

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I am trying to install Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update 2. Everything was going good but got below exception at the step "**InstallCommerceMAModule**"

> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : No registration found for extension
>   'ExpandArchive' of type 'Task'. At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253
>   char:21
>   +                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[image]

Added Script

```
#Requires -Version 3
param(
    [string]$SiteName = "sc9u2.sc", 
    [string]$SiteHostHeaderName = "storefront.local",   
    [string]$SqlDbPrefix = "sc9u2",
    [string]$CommerceSearchProvider = "SOLR"
)

$global:DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$modulesPath=( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "Modules" )
if ($env:PSModulePath -notlike "*$modulesPath*")
{
    $p = $env:PSModulePath + ";" + $modulesPath
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath",$p)
}


$params = @{
        Path = Resolve-Path '.\Configuration\Commerce\Master_SingleServer.json' 
        SiteName = $SiteName
        SiteHostHeaderName = $SiteHostHeaderName 
        InstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\$SiteName"
        XConnectInstallDir = "$($Env:SYSTEMDRIVE)\inetpub\wwwroot\sc9u2.xconnect"
        CertificateName = $SiteName
        CommerceServicesDbServer = "DESKTOP-O8SPMPV\SQLEXPRESS"    #OR "SQLServerName\SQLInstanceName"
        CommerceServicesDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments"
        CommerceServicesGlobalDbName = "SitecoreCommerce9_Global"       
        SitecoreDbServer = "DESKTOP-O8SPMPV\SQLEXPRESS"            #OR "SQLServerName\SQLInstanceName"
        SitecoreCoreDbName = "$($SqlDbPrefix)_Core"
        SitecoreUsername = "sitecore\admin"
        SitecoreUserPassword = "b"
        CommerceSearchProvider = $CommerceSearchProvider
        SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8984/solr"
        SolrRoot = "C:\Sitecore9\solr-6.6.2"
        SolrService = "Solr"
        SolrSchemas = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SolrSchemas" )
        SearchIndexPrefix = ""
        AzureSearchServiceName = ""
        AzureSearchAdminKey = ""
        AzureSearchQueryKey = ""
        CommerceEngineDacPac = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.*\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DB.dacpac"       
        CommerceOpsServicesPort = "5015"
        CommerceShopsServicesPort = "5005"
        CommerceAuthoringServicesPort = "5000"
        CommerceMinionsServicesPort = "5010"        
        SitecoreCommerceEngineZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.2.2.126.zip"        
        SitecoreBizFxServicesContentPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.BizFX.1.2.19"        
        SitecoreIdentityServerZipPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.IdentityServer.1.*.zip"
        CommerceEngineCertificatePath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\storefront.local.cer"        
        SiteUtilitiesSrc = ( Join-Path -Path $DEPLOYMENT_DIRECTORY -ChildPath "SiteUtilityPages" )  
        HabitatImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Habitat.Images-*.zip"    
        AdvImagesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Adventure Works Images.zip"    
        CommerceConnectModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Connect*.zip"  
        CommercexProfilesModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce ExperienceProfile Core *.zip"    
        CommercexAnalyticsModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce ExperienceAnalytics Core *.zip" 
        CommerceMAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Marketing Automation Core *.zip"    
        CommerceMAForAutomationEngineModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Marketing Automation for AutomationEngine *.zip" 
        CEConnectPackageFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect*.update"
        PowerShellExtensionsModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.7.2 for Sitecore 8.zip"
        SXAModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.7 rev. 180410 for 9.0.zip"
        SXACommerceModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator 1.*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront 1.*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontThemeModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Storefront Themes*.zip"
        SXAStorefrontCatalogModuleFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Sitecore Commerce Experience Accelerator Habitat Catalog*.zip"
        MergeToolFullPath = Resolve-Path -Path "..\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
        UserAccount = @{
            Domain = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
            UserName = 'CSFndRuntimeUser'
            Password = 'Pu8azaCr'
        }
        BraintreeAccount = @{
            MerchantId = ''
            PublicKey = ''
            PrivateKey = ''
        }
        SitecoreIdentityServerName = "SitecoreIdentityServer"       
    }

if ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "SOLR") {
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params
}
elseif ($CommerceSearchProvider -eq "AZURE"){
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Skip InstallSolrCores
}
# SIG # Begin signature block
# MIIXwQYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIXsjCCF64CAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMGkGCisGAQQB
# gjcCAQSgWzBZMDQGCisGAQQBgjcCAR4wJgIDAQAABBAfzDtgWUsITrck0sYpfvNR
# AgEAAgEAAgEAAgEAAgEAMCEwCQYFKw4DAhoFAAQU2A4zbikI1U2u89We6OodK+3R
# VQ+gghL8MIID7jCCA1egAwIBAgIQfpPr+3zGTlnqS5p31Ab8OzANBgkqhkiG9w0B
# AQUFADCBizELMAkGA1UEBhMCWkExFTATBgNVBAgTDFdlc3Rlcm4gQ2FwZTEUMBIG
# A1UEBxMLRHVyYmFudmlsbGUxDzANBgNVBAoTBlRoYXd0ZTEdMBsGA1UECxMUVGhh
# d3RlIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24xHzAdBgNVBAMTFlRoYXd0ZSBUaW1lc3RhbXBpbmcg
# Q0EwHhcNMTIxMjIxMDAwMDAwWhcNMjAxMjMwMjM1OTU5WjBeMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
# UzEdMBsGA1UEChMUU3ltYW50ZWMgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24xMDAuBgNVBAMTJ1N5bWFu
# dGVjIFRpbWUgU3RhbXBpbmcgU2VydmljZXMgQ0EgLSBHMjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcN
# AQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALGss0lUS5ccEgrYJXmRIlcqb9y4JsRDc2vCvy5Q
# WvsUwnaOQwElQ7Sh4kX06Ld7w3TMIte0lAAC903tv7S3RCRrzV9FO9FEzkMScxeC
# i2m0K8uZHqxyGyZNcR+xMd37UWECU6aq9UksBXhFpS+JzueZ5/6M4lc/PcaS3Er4
# ezPkeQr78HWIQZz/xQNRmarXbJ+TaYdlKYOFwmAUxMjJOxTawIHwHw103pIiq8r3
# +3R8J+b3Sht/p8OeLa6K6qbmqicWfWH3mHERvOJQoUvlXfrlDqcsn6plINPYlujI
# fKVOSET/GeJEB5IL12iEgF1qeGRFzWBGflTBE3zFefHJwXECAwEAAaOB+jCB9zAd
# BgNVHQ4EFgQUX5r1blzMzHSa1N197z/b7EyALt0wMgYIKwYBBQUHAQEEJjAkMCIG
# CCsGAQUFBzABhhZodHRwOi8vb2NzcC50aGF3dGUuY29tMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYB
# Af8CAQAwPwYDVR0fBDgwNjA0oDKgMIYuaHR0cDovL2NybC50aGF3dGUuY29tL1Ro
# YXd0ZVRpbWVzdGFtcGluZ0NBLmNybDATBgNVHSUEDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDCDAOBgNV
# HQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwKAYDVR0RBCEwH6QdMBsxGTAXBgNVBAMTEFRpbWVTdGFtcC0y
# MDQ4LTEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAAwmbj3nvf1kwqu9otfrjCR27T4IGXTdf
# plKfFo3qHJIJRG71betYfDDo+WmNI3MLEm9Hqa45EfgqsZuwGsOO61mWAK3ODE2y
# 0DGmCFwqevzieh1XTKhlGOl5QGIllm7HxzdqgyEIjkHq3dlXPx13SYcqFgZepjhq
# IhKjURmDfrYwggSjMIIDi6ADAgECAhAOz/Q4yP6/NW4E2GqYGxpQMA0GCSqGSIb3
# DQEBBQUAMF4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMR0wGwYDVQQKExRTeW1hbnRlYyBDb3Jwb3Jh
# dGlvbjEwMC4GA1UEAxMnU3ltYW50ZWMgVGltZSBTdGFtcGluZyBTZXJ2aWNlcyBD
# QSAtIEcyMB4XDTEyMTAxODAwMDAwMFoXDTIwMTIyOTIzNTk1OVowYjELMAkGA1UE
# BhMCVVMxHTAbBgNVBAoTFFN5bWFudGVjIENvcnBvcmF0aW9uMTQwMgYDVQQDEytT
# eW1hbnRlYyBUaW1lIFN0YW1waW5nIFNlcnZpY2VzIFNpZ25lciAtIEc0MIIBIjAN
# BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAomMLOUS4uyOnREm7Dv+h8GEKU5Ow
# mNutLA9KxW7/hjxTVQ8VzgQ/K/2plpbZvmF5C1vJTIZ25eBDSyKV7sIrQ8Gf2Gi0
# jkBP7oU4uRHFI/JkWPAVMm9OV6GuiKQC1yoezUvh3WPVF4kyW7BemVqonShQDhfu
# ltthO0VRHc8SVguSR/yrrvZmPUescHLnkudfzRC5xINklBm9JYDh6NIipdC6Anqh
# d5NbZcPuF3S8QYYq3AhMjJKMkS2ed0QfaNaodHfbDlsyi1aLM73ZY8hJnTrFxeoz
# C9Lxoxv0i77Zs1eLO94Ep3oisiSuLsdwxb5OgyYI+wu9qU+ZCOEQKHKqzQIDAQAB
# o4IBVzCCAVMwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAWBgNVHSUBAf8EDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDCDAO
# BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwcwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEZzBlMCoGCCsGAQUFBzABhh5odHRw
# Oi8vdHMtb2NzcC53cy5zeW1hbnRlYy5jb20wNwYIKwYBBQUHMAKGK2h0dHA6Ly90
# cy1haWEud3Muc3ltYW50ZWMuY29tL3Rzcy1jYS1nMi5jZXIwPAYDVR0fBDUwMzAx
# oC+gLYYraHR0cDovL3RzLWNybC53cy5zeW1hbnRlYy5jb20vdHNzLWNhLWcyLmNy
# bDAoBgNVHREEITAfpB0wGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQVGltZVN0YW1wLTIwNDgtMjAdBgNV
# HQ4EFgQURsZpow5KFB7VTNpSYxc/Xja8DeYwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUX5r1blzMzHSa
# 1N197z/b7EyALt0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAHg7tJEqAEzwj2IwN3ijhCcH
# bxiy3iXcoNSUA6qGTiWfmkADHN3O43nLIWgG2rYytG2/9CwmYzPkSWRtDebDZw73
# BaQ1bHyJFsbpst+y6d0gxnEPzZV03LZc3r03H0N45ni1zSgEIKOq8UvEiCmRDoDR
# EfzdXHZuT14ORUZBbg2w6jiasTraCXEQ/Bx5tIB7rGn0/Zy2DBYr8X9bCT2bW+IW
# yhOBbQAuOA2oKY8s4bL0WqkBrxWcLC9JG9siu8P+eJRRw4axgohd8D20UaF5Mysu
# e7ncIAkTcetqGVvP6KUwVyyJST+5z3/Jvz4iaGNTmr1pdKzFHTx/kuDDvBzYBHUw
# ggUrMIIEE6ADAgECAhAHplztCw0v0TJNgwJhke9VMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMHIx
# CzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxGTAXBgNVBAsTEHd3
# dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20xMTAvBgNVBAMTKERpZ2lDZXJ0IFNIQTIgQXNzdXJlZCBJ
# RCBDb2RlIFNpZ25pbmcgQ0EwHhcNMTcwODIzMDAwMDAwWhcNMjAwOTMwMTIwMDAw
# WjBoMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UECBMCY2ExEjAQBgNVBAcTCVNhdXNhbGl0
# bzEbMBkGA1UEChMSU2l0ZWNvcmUgVVNBLCBJbmMuMRswGQYDVQQDExJTaXRlY29y
# ZSBVU0EsIEluYy4wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC7PZ/g
# huhrQ/p/0Cg7BRrYjw7ZMx8HNBamEm0El+sedPWYeAAFrjDSpECxYjvK8/NOS9dk
# tC35XL2TREMOJk746mZqia+g+NQDPEaDjNPG/iT0gWsOeCa9dUcIUtnBQ0hBKsuR
# bau3n7w1uIgr3zf29vc9NhCoz1m2uBNIuLBlkKguXwgPt4rzj66+18JV3xyLQJoS
# 3ZAA8k6FnZltNB+4HB0LKpPmF8PmAm5fhwGz6JFTKe+HCBRtuwOEERSd1EN7TGKi
# xczSX8FJMz84dcOfALxjTj6RUF5TNSQLD2pACgYWl8MM0lEtD/1eif7TKMHqaA+s
# m/yJrlKEtOr836BvAgMBAAGjggHFMIIBwTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBRaxLl7Kgqjpepx
# A8Bg+S32ZXUOWDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQULh60SWOBOnU9TSFq0c2sWmMdu7EwDgYDVR0P
# AQH/BAQDAgeAMBMGA1UdJQQMMAoGCCsGAQUFBwMDMHcGA1UdHwRwMG4wNaAzoDGG
# L2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwzLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9zaGEyLWFzc3VyZWQtY3MtZzEuY3Js
# MDWgM6Axhi9odHRwOi8vY3JsNC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vc2hhMi1hc3N1cmVkLWNz
# LWcxLmNybDBMBgNVHSAERTBDMDcGCWCGSAGG/WwDATAqMCgGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhxo
# dHRwczovL3d3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ1BTMAgGBmeBDAEEATCBhAYIKwYBBQUH
# AQEEeDB2MCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20wTgYI
# KwYBBQUHMAKGQmh0dHA6Ly9jYWNlcnRzLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydFNI
# QTJBc3N1cmVkSURDb2RlU2lnbmluZ0NBLmNydDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMA0GCSqG
# SIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQBozpJhBdsaz19E9faa/wtrnssUreKxZVkYQ+NViWeyImc5
# qEZcDPy3Qgf731kVPnYuwi5S0U+qyg5p1CNn/WsvnJsdw8aO0lseadu8PECuHj1Z
# 5w4mi5rGNq+QVYSBB2vBh5Ps5rXuifBFF8YnUyBc2KuWBOCq6MTRN1H2sU5LtOUc
# Qkacv8hyom8DHERbd3mIBkV8fmtAmvwFYOCsXdBHOSwQUvfs53GySrnIYiWT0y56
# mVYPwDj7h/PdWO5hIuZm6n5ohInLig1weiVDJ254r+2pfyyRT+02JVVxyHFMCLwC
# ASs4vgbiZzMDltmoTDHz9gULxu/CfBGM0waMDu3cMIIFMDCCBBigAwIBAgIQBAkY
# G1/Vu2Z1U0O1b5VQCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBlMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMG
# A1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSQw
# IgYDVQQDExtEaWdpQ2VydCBBc3N1cmVkIElEIFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMTMxMDIyMTIw
# MDAwWhcNMjgxMDIyMTIwMDAwWjByMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGln
# aUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMTEwLwYDVQQDEyhE
# aWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIEFzc3VyZWQgSUQgQ29kZSBTaWduaW5nIENBMIIBIjANBgkq
# hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA+NOzHH8OEa9ndwfTCzFJGc/Q+0WZsTrb
# RPV/5aid2zLXcep2nQUut4/6kkPApfmJ1DcZ17aq8JyGpdglrA55KDp+6dFn08b7
# KSfH03sjlOSRI5aQd4L5oYQjZhJUM1B0sSgmuyRpwsJS8hRniolF1C2ho+mILCCV
# rhxKhwjfDPXiTWAYvqrEsq5wMWYzcT6scKKrzn/pfMuSoeU7MRzP6vIK5Fe7SrXp
# dOYr/mzLfnQ5Ng2Q7+S1TqSp6moKq4TzrGdOtcT3jNEgJSPrCGQ+UpbB8g8S9MWO
# D8Gi6CxR93O8vYWxYoNzQYIH5DiLanMg0A9kczyen6Yzqf0Z3yWT0QIDAQABo4IB
# zTCCAckwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwEwYDVR0l
# BAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwMweQYIKwYBBQUHAQEEbTBrMCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRw
# Oi8vb2NzcC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20wQwYIKwYBBQUHMAKGN2h0dHA6Ly9jYWNlcnRz
# LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydEFzc3VyZWRJRFJvb3RDQS5jcnQwgYEGA1Ud
# HwR6MHgwOqA4oDaGNGh0dHA6Ly9jcmw0LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydEFz
# c3VyZWRJRFJvb3RDQS5jcmwwOqA4oDaGNGh0dHA6Ly9jcmwzLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNv
# bS9EaWdpQ2VydEFzc3VyZWRJRFJvb3RDQS5jcmwwTwYDVR0gBEgwRjA4BgpghkgB
# hv1sAAIEMCowKAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9D
# UFMwCgYIYIZIAYb9bAMwHQYDVR0OBBYEFFrEuXsqCqOl6nEDwGD5LfZldQ5YMB8G
# A1UdIwQYMBaAFEXroq/0ksuCMS1Ri6enIZ3zbcgPMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IB
# AQA+7A1aJLPzItEVyCx8JSl2qB1dHC06GsTvMGHXfgtg/cM9D8Svi/3vKt8gVTew
# 4fbRknUPUbRupY5a4l4kgU4QpO4/cY5jDhNLrddfRHnzNhQGivecRk5c/5CxGwcO
# kRX7uq+1UcKNJK4kxscnKqEpKBo6cSgCPC6Ro8AlEeKcFEehemhor5unXCBc2XGx
# DI+7qPjFEmifz0DLQESlE/DmZAwlCEIysjaKJAL+L3J+HNdJRZboWR3p+nRka7Lr
# ZkPas7CM1ekN3fYBIM6ZMWM9CBoYs4GbT8aTEAb8B4H6i9r5gkn3Ym6hU/oSlBiF
# LpKR6mhsRDKyZqHnGKSaZFHvMYIELzCCBCsCAQEwgYYwcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
# FTATBgNVBAoTDERpZ2lDZXJ0IEluYzEZMBcGA1UECxMQd3d3LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNv
# bTExMC8GA1UEAxMoRGlnaUNlcnQgU0hBMiBBc3N1cmVkIElEIENvZGUgU2lnbmlu
# ZyBDQQIQB6Zc7QsNL9EyTYMCYZHvVTAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoHAwEAYKKwYBBAGCNwIB
# DDECMAAwGQYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQwGCisGAQQBgjcCAQQwHAYKKwYBBAGCNwIBCzEO
# MAwGCisGAQQBgjcCARUwIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMRYEFFhL5ZmCLq9hUiVOrIhi7tNi
# NKdiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIIBAH/rxB1j9CVdi/h3Z5ID/mjQbwHTOfchRIjf
# Zbar9Os6ApXTt1BucBvWvjnuhBitrglg3Ye34VKfcrCwpwDMB9yYefVqhcQt6nmN
# j6jZ/jAbpQ1NUfacVp4j0vSJzdYJx6hBSvkCDOsYI8dE41dY9KG1qGO6ENeph7hN
# FlenP5jAvSgI7cP9SwSLhXqAYkafISStBoEDVDoImcebsqzdCLrI2vEfrJykekZJ
# bzLYTIdSBA239FLPLgfSi8JMxmR91buc9FxX5KuSBsBQ5WVAn7Zv35MIJ5YJ9/hC
# nfH7iYcDvbuK7UKW+qJ8/WeuXRtTQeYn7Rkr3pgED1vC0DcbBxOhggILMIICBwYJ
# KoZIhvcNAQkGMYIB+DCCAfQCAQEwcjBeMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEdMBsGA1UEChMU
# U3ltYW50ZWMgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24xMDAuBgNVBAMTJ1N5bWFudGVjIFRpbWUgU3Rh
# bXBpbmcgU2VydmljZXMgQ0EgLSBHMgIQDs/0OMj+vzVuBNhqmBsaUDAJBgUrDgMC
# GgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcN
# MTgwNjE0MTc1MTQwWjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQU4dRV4mrmlmo23fz23U6f5lkM
# xjAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAe2TShd9FJInWxz/vZmn/mBW8zhOXCHPGgSz8
# pJr3BG0aBJ1wOoglnqwS9fEdHjs/RLHdXEKVBo5KSaPWeC2fYGLR43sTCcqwNTsX
# LEAfg9DrbiJLcB49od00oge74MXvfCb6eqBPVbCPTcgjlt+UyJ3ldRo/gUVH5Mly
# GRVlrdRXxGIvTrCxJdQ4u8zMhHSie4R2aWzv6L0TF63uIIFoVxpnzQNGKNftn3jt
# 2UU34gYl4I8e1vPpAoFfPLHWMi/qr7mqjg4LVQnNMpRyJuzGmoBXMFmBnLgkPecu
# tjnbFxotTOEywlOHvIg9F4JRRQ7TSya7+I56fWz7M2b7vWx8hg==
# SIG # End signature block
```

Comment: I had the same issue today. I just re-run the install script second time(no changes to the script) and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I did multiple times but result were always same and at same step.

Comment: Can you upfate your question with your deployment ps1 script?

Comment: @PeterProchazka, updated the question with depoyment .pls1 script. Thanks

Comment: Based on SitecoreDBServer parameter in your ps1 script I assume that you are using SQL Express. Could be that this is affecting your installation as this is not supported based on Installation guide. You should you SQL Server 2016 SP1. Can you please try to install this one instead and try once again?